# ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync throws UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to store a file to the app's storage in a Windows Phone 8.1 app, but it always fails with a System.**UnauthorizedAccessException**.

The exception occurs on the following line (no related code before that):

```
StorageFile storageFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("test.xml", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

Comment: At what moment do you try to create the file?

Comment: I am doing this in the OnNavigatedTo method of the page.

Comment: Are you awaiting on this line? Or you just call it as you have written?

Comment: Yes, I am. I updated the code snippet I posted above to represent the entire line of code I am using.

Comment: As it is run async, check if something else is not trying to use the same file. Also try to set a breakpoint at that line (or line before) and step over - see what happens.

Comment: Nothing else inside my app is using that file, I only have this one line of code that uses "test.xml".

Setting a breakpoint on that line I see it throwing the exception shortly after I step over it (F10).

Comment: I've tried this line and it's working fine. The main question is - what kind of project are you trying to build? WP8 or WP8.1?

Comment: WP8.1, which one did you use? I literally created a new project of type "Blank App (Windows Phone)", added the above line to the MainPage's OnNavigatedTo stub and changed that method to be async, nothing else.

Comment: What emulator or device are you using to run the code in? Have you tried replacing ReplaceExisting with another option?

Comment: I am using the Windows Phone 8.1 emulator. I uninstalled Visual Studio and re-installed Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 RC and re-installed the emulator from within Visual Studio, still no luck, same exception. 

The exception is no longer present in the clean new project, not sure how it disappeared. I got it to go away in my project for a short duration, too, after I added and removed the 'local storage' capability. When I played around with it for a while it came back though. :\

Comment: I just tried your suggestion and changed it from ReplaceExisting to GenerateUniqueName. This made it work, now I get the UnauthorizedAccessException when reading that file.

Comment: What is the 'local storage' capability you are using? I don't see one called local storage listed here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464936.aspx

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped that. I was enabling/disabling the "Removable Storage" capability.

I actually shared the code with a friend who ran it on his phone and he is not getting this exception with the exact same code. :/

Comment: It is working again at the moment. I was calling CreateFileAsync from a static method before. Changing that method to be non-static fixed this. Any idea what the reason for this is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found the issue:

I had a call to

```
Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.DeleteAsync()
```

in code that ran once after installing the app. Therefore all writing to this folder failed after that point.

I am not sure why `GenerateUniqueName` made the UnauthorizedAccessException disappear before, but since I wasn't able to read the file when using `GenerateUniqueName` I assume that specific code path doesn't ever throw that exception for some reason, maybe because it assumes there can never be an issue when using unique file names.

Comment: Awesome! I just had the same problem. I'd never found this without your hint.